# PHP cURL stream big file : can't avoid using RAM

Tags: php, curl, stream, download

I got a little problem while deserving big files from distant server to client with cURL;

The problem is, it seems that the download is set in RAM while it's rendered to the client...

I'm using cURL because I need a cookie auth :/

Here is a little example :

```
function streamContent($url)
{
    session_write_close();

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'mycookie');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'mycookie');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, "progress");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "streamHeader");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, "myProgressFunc");

    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}


function myProgressFunc($curl, $str)
{ 
    echo $str;

    return strlen($str);
}

function progress($curl, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) {
    $r = fopen('test_for_tail.txt', 'a+');
    $time = microtime(true);
    fputs($r, $time.' - '.$downloaded.'/'.$download_size.PHP_EOL);
    fclose($r);
}

function streamHeader($curl, $string)
{
    $stringTrim = trim($string);
    if(!empty ($stringTrim)) {
        if(!preg_match('~chunk~i', $stringTrim)) header($stringTrim);
    }

    return strlen($string);
}

$file = '.....';
streamContent($file);
```

Now, I launch the script in a browser for instance, and do a "tail -f test_for_tail.txt"

The file "test_for_tail.txt" is fill, but when I set the download on "pause", the file continues to be fill...
If I stop the download, then the process if broke, that's good.

I suppose the "test_for_tail.txt" file is fill because the download is done on RAM before giving it to the client

Can I avoid that ?

Because 100 files with 2go by file and I'm dead... ^^

The goal is to stream the file to the client, without putting all of it in RAM, and let the user pause and resume the download when he want

Thanks !

Comment: use `CURLOPT_FILE`, and point it at `php://stdout`?

Comment: Nop, doesn't work :/ same result